# Generate a string that is not present in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, homework

For a college assignment, I was tasked with the following (excerpt from provided code file):

> Find one string of characters that is not present in the list. You are provided a function
> that loads the strings from the provided file, `sequences.txt`. You may not use any libraries that assist you in completing this solution.
> This specifically includes the `random` and `string` library. Your function must return two values: the string not present in the list, and a boolean value
> representing if the value is present in the list. Ensure to use documentation strings and comments
> to explain your program! Good luck!

Below is my solution, with a description of the algorithm is provided in the docstring. The main thing I'm worried about is my solution. I'm concerned there is a much easier solution, just not as elegant; like switching the first character of the first string and comparing that. It's not a 100% sure solution, but I'm sure it works most of the time. Mine is a sure solution, from my understanding.

I should mention, the file `sequences.txt` contains 1000 lines, where each line is 1000 characters long, each character either A or B.

Any and all critiques and recommendations are welcome and considered!

```
"""
Find one string of characters that is not present in the list. You are provided a function
that loads the strings from the provided file, `sequences.txt`.

You may not use any libraries that assist you in completing this solution.
This specifically includes the `random` and `string` library.

Your function must return two values: the string not present in the list, and a boolean value
representing if the value is present in the list. Ensure to use documentation strings and comments
to explain your program! Good luck!

@professor XXXXXXXX
@class CS 1350
@due Nov 15, 2021

Provide your details below:

@author Ben Antonellis
@date Nov 2nd, 2021
"""

# PROVIDED FUNCTIONS #

def load_sequences():
    sequences = []
    with open('sequences.txt', 'r') as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            sequences.append(line.strip())
    return sequences


# PROVIDE YOUR SOLUTION BELOW #

from typing import Tuple # For code clarity

def find_excluded() -> Tuple[str, bool]:
    """
    This algorithm marches through each string in the list, and for every string
    flips the n-th character. By doing this, this ensures the string is different
    from each string by at least one character.
    """
    strings = load_sequences()
    string_index = 0
    result = ""
    for idx, _ in enumerate(strings):
        result += "A" if strings[idx][string_index] == "B" else "B"
        string_index += 1
    return result, result in strings


result, should_be_false = find_excluded()
print(result)
print(should_be_false)
```

Comment: I think you forgot to increment the string index. As is this would fail with the following input of 2 strings : 'AB', 'BA' . But would work with strings[idx][idx].

Comment: @kubatucka Thanks for the catch, somehow that didn't make it into the copy-paste!

Comment: How returning empty string (or any other less-then-1000-long string) fails to meet the requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct and will always provide a correct answer as the list length equals the string length. As @Toby already pointed out you shall not maintain two indices as you walk row and column on a diagonal.

Additionally I want to give two more points.

## Do not mix in the I/O operation with your processing function

That does bind your algorithm to the filename and does not allow generic usage and testing. Instead do a function that takes a list of strings and returns a single string. As your algorithm always provides a solution there is no need to return the truth value other than your appointment of course.

```
def find_excluded(strings: str) -> Tuple[str, bool]:
    s = ...
    return (s, False)
```

which you use then like

```
strings = load_sequences()
result, should_be_false = find_excluded(strings)
```

Now we can easily do simple tests like

```
strings = ["AA", "AB"]
result, _ = find_excluded(strings)
assert len(result) == len(strings)
assert result not in strings
```

You can also test edge cases etc.

## Try to think in algorithms/filters applied to sequences of data

This is very often much more readable and self documenting if you chose good names for your temporaries/functions/expressions. As your algorithm walks the diagonal we name a temporary like that. For the character replacemaent a name like 'invert' sounds nice as the code is binary.

```
def find_excluded(strings: str) -> Tuple[str, bool]:
    diagonal = [s[i] for i, s in enumerate(strings)]
    invert = {'A':'B', 'B':'A'}
    inverted = [invert[c] for c in diagonal]
    return (''.join(inverted), False)
```

That is pretty readdable, isn't it? Note: you may replace the list comprehensions by generator expressions. That allows working on big iterables efficiently.

```
def find_excluded(strings: str) -> Tuple[str, bool]:
    diagonal = (s[i] for i, s in enumerate(strings))
    invert = {'A':'B', 'B':'A'}
    inverted = (invert[c] for c in diagonal)
    return (''.join(inverted), False)
```

Answer (score 2):

We should begin the habit of using a "main guard":

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    result, should_be_false = find_excluded()
    print(result)
    print(should_be_false)
```

We don't need `strings[idx]`, since `enumerate()` is already giving us that.  We just have to not ignore it.  And `string_index` is always kept equal to `idx`, so no need to maintain a separate variable.

```
for idx, s in enumerate(strings):
    result += "A" if s[idx] == "B" else "B"
```

Or construct the result string from a comprehension (with a more cute selection, using array indexing):

```
result = ''.join("BA"[s[i]=="B"] for i,s in enumerate(strings))
```

I note that the assignment is not yet due; if you've not submitted yet, remember to acknowledge the help you received here.